# Highlight repeating strings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have up to three almost-identical divs that contain tables of usernames. Some names may be repeated across the three divs. I'd like to highlight the names that are repeated. The first occurrence of the user should not be colored, the second occurrence should have an orange background and the third should have a red background. The divs go from left to right in order so the first div should not have any highlighted usernames.

My HTML looks like:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>2/26/2014</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>user1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>user2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>user5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>user17</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>2/27/2014</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>user13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>user5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>user7</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>2/28/2014</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>user5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>user45</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>user1</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I know that the username table cells will be selected with `$('table.table td')` (if I use jQuery) but I'm not sure what to do from there.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post any of your current code you have issues with so we can have a look why it might not be working? I assume you at least have some basic code that loops through the divs/tables or similar?

Comment: That's all I've got to show, actually. I'm not sure how I can loop through each table and compare contents.

Comment: I believe that I have figured it out. Check my answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[image]

I created a map to store text-occurrence pairs. Each time the text is repeated, the counter associated with it gets incremented. If the counter climbs to a certain value, the background will be set to another color. Give it a shot!

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jUtnE/1/)</kbd>

```
var map = new Object();

$('td').each(function() {
    var prop = $(this).text()
    var bgColor = '#FFFFFF';

    if (map[prop] > 1) {
        bgColor = '#FF0000';
    } else if (map[prop] > 0) {
        bgColor = '#FF7F00';
    }

    $(this).css('background', bgColor);

    if (map.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        map[prop]++;
    } else {
        map[prop] = 1;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this but I didn't test it

```
$('td').each(function(){
  var text = this.html();
  $('td:contains("'+text+'"):nth-child(2)').css({'background':'orange'});
  $('td:contains("'+text+'"):nth-child(3)').css({'background':'red'});
});
```

**Edit:**

Not particularly elegant but it seems to work

http://jsfiddle.net/63L7L/1/

```
var second = [];
var third = [];
$('td').each(function(){
  var text = $(this).html();
  second.push($("td").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === text;
 })[1])
   third.push($("td").filter(function() {
   return $(this).text() === text;
 })[2])
}); 

  $(second).each(function(){
   $(this).css({'background':'red'});
  });

  $(third).each(function(){
  $(this).css({'background':'orange'});

});
```

Comment: It's this: `var text = $(this).text();` and no, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

With pure Javascript (ECMA5)

CSS

```
.orange {
    background-color:orange;
}
.red {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Javascript

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.table-striped td'), function (td) {
    var textContent = td.textContent;

    if (this.hasOwnProperty(textContent)) {
        td.classList.add(++this[textContent] === 2 ? 'orange' : 'red');
    } else {
        this[textContent] = 1;
    }
}, {});
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/98Rtt/)